# Reassigning Bean Value

Tags: jsp, variables, initialization, javabeans, variable-assignment

In my jsp page, I have a javabean instatiated thusly:

```
<bean:define id="thisReadOnly" value="false" type="java.lang.String"/>
```

This is perfectly fine.  However, it is not quite what I want.

What I want to do is to be able to overwrite that value given a certain condition.

However, I have had no luck in figuring out HOW to reassign that value through numerous search attempts.

How can I redefine the value of this bean, such that it would read "true" instead of "false"?

Comment: Your JSP is supposed to be the "view" of your webapplication, hence variable-reassignement is a bad idea here. Why do you want to reassign a bean value in your JSP? The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: I've found a workaround, but the reason is that the flow of our page is dependent on the state of that bean, which is determined by an if/else switch that determines how the bean should be defined.